# NLTK python error: "TypeError: 'dict_keys' object is not subscriptable"

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, key, nltk

I'm following instructions for a class homework assignment and I'm supposed to look up the top 200 most frequently used words in a text file.

Here's the last part of the code:

```py
fdist1 = FreqDist(NSmyText)
vocab=fdist1.keys()
vocab[:200]
```

But when I press enter after the vocab 200 line, it returns:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'dict_keys' object is not subscriptable
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this so it can correctly return an answer?

Comment: The stack trace does not match the code you have shown. Can you copy paste the *exact* code, and the error message?

Comment: Is there a way to copy and paste text from/into the terminal? So far I have not been able to figure it out.

Comment: Need the `import` line to make sense of the snippet.

Answer (score 182, accepted):

Looks like you are using Python 3. In Python 3 `dict.keys()` returns an iterable but not indexable object. The most simple (but not so efficient) solution would be:

```
vocab = list(fdist1.keys())[:200]
```

In some situations it is desirable to continue working with an  iterator object instead of a list. This can be done with `itertools.islice()`:

```
import itertools
vocab_iterator = itertools.islice(fdist1.keys(), 200)
```

Comment: You might as well have written `vocab = list(fdist1)`

Comment: _Iterables_ are the basis of list operations in python3 and they need to be completed by _list(iterable)_ : that is common not rare.  I complain about a language to try to learn how to better adapt to the limitations.

Answer (score 14):

I am using `python 3.5` and I meet the same problem of   `TypeError`.

Using `vocab = list(fdist1.keys())` does not give me the top 50 most frequently used words.
But `fdist1.most_common(50)` does.

Further,if you just want to show those top 50 words not with their frequency,you can try :

`[word for (word, freq) in fdist1.most_common(50)]`

Comment: imho this is a much more helpful response because it provides an example of the most_common() function which is what OP asked for.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get elements as keys and values (word and frequency), you can use:

`list(fdist1.items())[:200]`

Answer (score 1):

To print the most frequently used 200 words use:
    fdist1.most_common(200)
The above line of code will return the 200 most frequently used words as key-frequency pair.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error below:

> TypeError: 'dict_items' object is not subscriptable

> TypeError: 'dict_keys' object is not subscriptable

> TypeError: 'dict_values' object is not subscriptable

When running `items()[0]`, `keys()[0]` and `values()[0]` with the dictionary `person` as shown below:

```py
person = {'name':'John', 'age':35}

print(person.items()[0]) # Error
print(person.keys()[0]) # Error
print(person.values()[0]) # Error
```

So, I use [list()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-list) as shown below, then the error is solved:

```py
person = {'name':'John', 'age':35}

print(list(person.items())[0]) # ('name', 'John')
print(list(person.keys())[0]) # name
print(list(person.values())[0]) # John
```

Answer (score 0):

If your using python 3 try:

```
fdist1.most_common(200)
```

instead, to get the 200 most frequent words.

Comment: This is a misleading answer.
this is the "collection" library and not mentioned here how to import..

I don't do downvotes but either give a full example or a link.

Answer (score 0):

`fdist1 = FreqDist(NSmyText)`

`vocab=fdist1.keys()`

This code is using in Python2.7.
So you should do some change.
dic.keys() returns an iteratable. So using:

`list(fdist1.keys())`