# Dictionary value

Tags: python, dictionary, bellman-ford

```
def get_neighbors_link_cost(source_id, network_topology):
    nodes = network_topology['nodes']


# get network topology links
links = network_topology['links'].keys()
#print(links)

# get the link costs in network topology
link_cost = network_topology['links']
#print(link_cost)

# make an empty dictionary for neighbor_link_cost
#neighbor_link_cost = None
neighbor_link_cost = {}

# add the cost to the source_id as zero
#neighbor_link_cost[None] = None
neighbor_link_cost[source_id] = 0
#print(neighbor_link_cost)

# go through the link
for link in links:
    # if source id is not in the link, skip it
    if source_id not in link:
        continue
    # get the neighbor information and cost for this neighbor
    neighbor = link[0] if source_id == link[1] else link[1]
    #neighbor_link_cost[None] = None
    #neighbor_link_cost[neighbor] = 3
    neighbor_link_cost[neighbor] = link(source_id,neighbor)
    #neighbor_link_cost[neighbor] = link_cost.get('z','x')
    #print(neighbor_link_cost[neighbor])

return neighbor_link_cost

network_topology = {'nodes': set(['z','x','y','w','v','u','t']),
              'links': {('z','x'): 8,
                        ('z','y'): 12,
                        ('x','y'): 6,
                        ('x','w'): 6,
                        ('x','v'): 3,
                        ('y','t'): 7,
                        ('y','v'): 8,
                        ('v','t'): 4,
                        ('v','w'): 4,
                        ('v','u'): 3,
                        ('t','u'): 2,
                        ('w','u'): 3
                       }
                   }

source_id = 'v'
get_neighbors_link_cost(source_id, network_top)
```

Expected output should be:

```
Expected output: {'v': 0, 'x': 3, 'y': 8, 't': 4, 'w': 4, 'u': 3}
```

What should be this line to get expected output? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
neighbor_link_cost[neighbor] = link(source_id,neighbor)
```

> 'tuple' object is not callable

change this to

```
neighbor_link_cost[neighbor] = links[link]
```

Comment: It doesn't work
TypeError: 'dict_keys' object is not subscriptable

Comment: you might look into this [Try](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26394748/nltk-python-error-typeerror-dict-keys-object-is-not-subscriptable)

Answer (score 0):

you're really close, just need to change:

```
neighbor_link_cost[neighbor] = link(source_id,neighbor)
```

to:

```
neighbor_link_cost[neighbor[source_id]] = link_cost[link]
```

then should get expected output.