# 'dict_keys' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am learning `random` function on Python 3 with this example, getting an error as the post title. `'dict_keys' object is not subscriptable`. I am not sure where i did wrong with `dictionary`.

```
import random
outcomes = {
        'heads':0, 
        'tails':0
        }

sides = outcomes.keys()

for i in range(100):
    outcomes[random.choice(sides)] += 1

print("Heads:", outcomes['heads'])
print("Tails:", outcomes['tails'])
```

Below is the error output

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-f58aad35f1b0> in <module>
      8 
      9 for i in range(100):
---> 10     outcomes[random.choice(sides)] += 1
     11 
     12 print('Heads:', outcomes['heads'])

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\random.py in choice(self, seq)
    260         except ValueError:
    261             raise IndexError('Cannot choose from an empty sequence') from None
--> 262         return seq[i]
    263 
    264     def shuffle(self, x, random=None):

TypeError: 'dict_keys' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: What line is the error on?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NLTK python error: "TypeError: 'dict\_keys' object is not subscriptable"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26394748/nltk-python-error-typeerror-dict-keys-object-is-not-subscriptable)
Do `random.choice(list(sides))`

Comment: @AmourK yes, it is a " list ". I accept your answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`choices` picks a number in the range of the size of the list passed as argument, and then tries to return the element at that index.

`keys()` return a set, which doesn't have indexes.

You need a list to use `choice`:

`sides = list(outcome.keys())`