# Is there a way i can access these Rates in python 3.8 without getting a TypeError: 'dict_keys' object is not subscriptable?

Tags: python, dictionary

```
RATES = {
        "Australian Dollar":1.4099,
        "Brazilian Real":3.7927,
        "Canadian dollar":1.3375,
        "Switzerland Franc":0.9964,
        "China Yuan":6.7131,
        "Euro":0.8845,
        "United Kingdom Pound":0.763,
        "Hungarian Forint":279.337,
        "Indian Rupees":68.98,
        "Japanese Yen":110.5194,
        "Kenyan shilling":100.6989,
        "Korean Won":1133.5973,
        "Malawian Kwacha":723.985,
        "New Zealand dollar":1.4558,
        "Oman Riyal":0.385,
        "Tanzanian Shilling":2344.103,
        "Ugandan Shilling":3708.5025,
        "United States Dollar":1,
        "South African Rand":14.3397,
        "Zambian Kwacha":12.029
        }
```

variable = tk.StringVar()
variable.set(None)

self.opt = tk.OptionMenu(self.frame, variable, *RATES, relief = 'raised', bd =2, width = 8, bg = '#008085')
self.opt.grid(row = 2, column = 2, padx = 10, pady = 10)

Comment: You'll also need to show us some code that accesses this. The dict literal you have here won't do much on its own.

Comment: Have you checked https://stackoverflow.com/a/26394855/1817690 ?

Comment: i have and implemented what was advised but i still get the same error

Comment: let me add some more code for you guys to understand my question better

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are trying to access Dictionary View Objects (https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects)

Some examples from Python docs website

```
>>> dishes = {'eggs': 2, 'sausage': 1, 'bacon': 1, 'spam': 500}
>>> keys = dishes.keys()
>>> values = dishes.values()

>>> # iteration
>>> n = 0
>>> for val in values:
...     n += val
>>> print(n)
504

>>> # keys and values are iterated over in the same order (insertion order)
>>> list(keys)
['eggs', 'sausage', 'bacon', 'spam']
>>> list(values)
[2, 1, 1, 500]

>>> # view objects are dynamic and reflect dict changes
>>> del dishes['eggs']
>>> del dishes['sausage']
>>> list(keys)
['bacon', 'spam']

>>> # set operations
>>> keys & {'eggs', 'bacon', 'salad'}
{'bacon'}
>>> keys ^ {'sausage', 'juice'}
{'juice', 'sausage', 'bacon', 'spam'}
```

So basically you can iterate over it (using `for key in RATES.keys()` loop), or just convert it to list using `print(list(RATES.keys()))` or `print(list(RATES.values()))`

Comment: You welcome! Feel free to accept & vote up the answer =)