# Accessing the first key in a nested Dictionary

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have a dictionary that looks like the following:

```
{
"DICT_KEY1": {"nestKey1": "val", "nestKey2": "val", "nestKey3": "val"}
}
```

If I have a function that takes in a parameter like the dictionary above,
How would I access the key "DICT_KEY1" (not the values) without mentioning "DICT_KEY1" (since the nested dictionary passed into the parameter would be different each time)?

I can only think of accessing DICT_KEY1 by mentioning the key name, like:

```
dict1 = {(nested dictionary param)}
print(dict1['DICT_KEY1'])
```

Comment: You can do `next(dict1)` to get the first key according to insertion order.  Or `min(dict1)` to get the first one according to order.

Comment: `DICT_KEY1` is not in the nested dictionary, it's in the top-level dictionary.

Comment: `print(dict1['DICT_KEY1'])` prints the value of that key, not the key. You said you're not interested in the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most efficient way to achieve that is using next() + iter() being the time complexity of this O(1).

```
print(next(iter(dict1)))
```

Transforming the keys of the dictionary into a list and accessing the first element will take O(n), what make that inneficient for bigger dictionaries.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `list(dict.keys())` to access the keys as a list.

For instance:

```
d = {"DICT_KEY1": {"nestKey1": "val", "nestKey2": "val", "nestKey3": "val"}}
print(list(d.keys()[0])
```

This is fine for small dictionaries, but can be inefficient for large ones. If you have a bigger dictionary, using a library might be more appropriate. See [this post for more guidance with third party libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26394855/18775765).